# android studio compiler not works win11 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I'm trying compiling app android with android studio but following error appears:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each request requires the same not
> null build mode to be set     at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl.executeAssembleTasks(GradleBuildInvokerImpl.kt:166)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl.assemble(GradleBuildInvokerImpl.kt:212)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl.assemble(GradleBuildInvokerImpl.kt:206)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.MakeGradleProjectAction.doPerform(MakeGradleProjectAction.java:46)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidStudioGradleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidStudioGradleAction.java:63)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:327)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:306)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:350)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:306)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$performAction$5(ActionMenuItem.java:296)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:226)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:289)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$new$0(ActionMenuItem.java:64)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$4(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
> at
> com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:526)
> at
> com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:558)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:831)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:753)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

can someone help me?

Comment: Please post that in a code block so the lines are preserved. Make it readable.